# CSS animated background not moving

Tags: html, css, animation, xslt, position

I've been creating an animated background, where there's a plain background colour, and then five objects which move across at different speeds and positions. I've got it to work in files on its own with no other code, but when I've placed it into my main document, it won't work as it does when it's on its own.

I have an xsl document with the html etc in, and then a separate document with the css in.

The xsl, with code not relevant to this taken out is...

```
<html>
    <head>  
        <title>Blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="blog.css" />
        <script src ="JavaScript.js"> </script>
    </head>

    <div class="star1"></div>
    <div class="star2"></div>
    <div class="star3"></div>
    <div class="star4"></div>
    <div class="star5"></div>

    <body>
    ...
    </body>
</html>
```

The divs are each object which is moving across, which are working in the separate document, and I have a feeling my problem is to do with positioning of everything, but I've tried different variations of relative and absolute positioning and neither seem to be working as I hope. In the below, each star is defined as set in the xsl, but instead of moving as they do when out of it, they're just sitting there in a cluster not moving.

```
html 
{ 
    padding: 100px 0;
}

body
{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #0A0F1A no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
}

/*background moved and forms here*/
.star1 
{
    width: 150px; 
    height: 150px;
    background: url(Images/Star1.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;


    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;

    -webkit-animation: movestar 30s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: movestar 30s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: movestar 30s linear infinite;
}

.star2
{
    width: 120px; 
    height: 120px;
    background: url(Images/Star2.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 400px; 

    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;

    -webkit-animation: movestar 50s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: movestar 50s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: movestar 50s linear infinite;
}

.star3
{
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
    background: url(Images/Star3.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: -400px;

    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;

    -webkit-animation: movestar 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: movestar 20s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: movestar 20s linear infinite;
}

.star4
{
    width: 80px; 
    height: 80px;
    background: url(Images/Star4.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: -200px; 

    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;

    -webkit-animation: movestar 10s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: movestar 10s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: movestar 10s linear infinite;
}

.star5
{
    width: 60px; 
    height: 60px;
    background: url(Images/Star5.png); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px; 

    border-radius: 200px;
    -moz-border-radius: 200px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 200px;

    -webkit-animation: movestar 30s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: movestar 30s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: movestar 30s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes movestar 
{
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-moz-keyframes movestar 
{
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
@-o-keyframes movestar 
{
    0% {margin-left: 1000px;}
    100% {margin-left: -1000px;}
}
```

Any help as to why it's not animated like it was before would be hugely appreciated as I've ran out of ideas of how to try fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add to jsfiddle?

Comment: They are moving for me : http://jsfiddle.net/yLn8ozxb/

Comment: That's totally bizzare, when I add it to jsfiddle, it's moving for me too... But when I load it on my laptop it's not.

Comment: not moving for me in opera but works fine in chrome. what browser you using. maybe it's a prefix issue

Comment: @Billy I've tried Firefox, Chrome and IE to check and it's not working in any. In jsfiddle, the <head> tags and what's in them are removed, so I'm wondering if it's something to do with the placement of the code around/in them. Edited code above with this extra info just in case.

Comment: Ah, problem found, when I import my xml information in and save it as an xsl file not html, the objects then don't move. Not sure how to solve this though.